# playframework 1.2.5, continuations, how to close the response/socket?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have some code like their example like so(untested as of yet)....

```
    Promise<Object> promise = new Promise<Object>();
    response.contentType = "application/json";
    JsonStreamer streamer = new JsonStreamer(columns, promise);
    while(streamer.hasMoreData()) {
          await(promise);
          response.writeChunk(streamer.nextDataChunk());
    }
```

What I don't get is how do I release the socket that the client opened?  I am streaming some very large data back in json.  I need some kind of response.releaseSocket() after writing the last chunk.  I see WebSockets has that but what about when I am using the await stuff?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah, I think it is noticing I never called await and in that case closes the socket.  If I call await, it knows to keep the socket open.  That makes sense.